# JavaFX how to push edited data to database

Tags: database, user-interface, javafx, sqlite

I need one more thing in my gui,and I don't know how I can do it.
I need to update data (after editing) by click on save button. How i can make it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this

```
Button saveButton = new Button("Save");
saveButton.setOnAction(event -> updateData());
```